# The font color of UILabel does not change on iOS 12

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

I had UILabel in my tableview cell, I'm trying to change the font color programmatically by adding a function as an extensions to UILabel, This is my extension

```
extension UILabel {
    func changeLblFontColorToRed(isRed: Bool) {
        isRed ? (self.textColor = Color.NavColor) : (self.textColor = Color.Green)
    }
}
```

It works fine in iOS 13 am calling it inside **cellForRowAt**, but in iOS 12 it doesn't work until I call the function inside the main thread.

Does anybody know the reason for this?

Comment: It's unclear. cellForRowAt isn't called in main thread? Shouldn't it be? Where are you calling it?

Comment: @Larme when i create my cell inside cellForRowAt i call my function to change the color

Comment: Could you try changing the colour in 'willDispayCell

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the code that works and the code that does not work.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? I am facing the similar issue